# Unwanted sound while recording Fender P Bass

Tags: bass-guitar, recording

When I try to record my Fender P bass, I get a small unwanted sound along. I am posting a sample: 
http://host.jsplash.com/audio/Sound-Bass.wav

Is this a hum, hiss, noise or what? Is it normal? What is the reason for this? How can I avoid this. If I cannot avoid, is there a way I can remove this after recording?

Comment: It would be nice to know the recording setup, i.e. the signal path from bass to recorder, and what type of recorder it is.

Comment: @Dave I am connecting my bass directly to my audio interface which is connected to my PC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adjust the pickups away from the strings and see if that helps.

I'm pretty sure (Read: Not 100% positive) I've heard that problem with PBasses in the past.

Comment: I adjusted the pickup heights (not exactly moved it away from the strings) and the problem went away. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I can't determine by ear if it's mechanical (probably only relevant for microphone recording) or electrical:

Mechanical: make sure that nothing in the room resonates with any of the frequencies you're playing, you should be able to diagnose this just by ear.

Electrical: try to put some distance between the recording device and the other parts of the signal chain.  Computers can be very noisy.

As for removing it, you could try using an equalizer; high-cut or a tight notch at the offending frequencies might help.